# $A^\dagger$ - how to handwrite this?!

Tags: notation

In one book I came across the notation $A^\dagger := \overline{A}^T$. But how does one usually handwrite it? When I try to do it, it seems so similar to $A^+$

Comment: It is usually referred to as a "dagger", which is common notation for the "Hermitian Adjoint" of a matrix. Another common notation is $A^*$

Comment: The notation $A^+$ often would not have any particular meaning, it thus many not be  much of a problem.

Comment: @quid, some literature use it to denote the Moore-Penrose inverse; one could conceivably see a linear algebra paper where conjugate transposition and taking the pseudoinverse of a matrix are both done. (In that case, I would follow Siddharth's first suggestion.)

Comment: @J.M. Yes I agree with both. Maybe let us throw some more stuff in the mix like $  L^T L^\perp T^{\dagger}T^+ $. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of people use $A^*$ to represent the Conjugate Transpose.

To actually draw the dagger, draw a really long vertical line, dashed with a small horizontal. I personally dash the horizontal at an angle when I'm doing this so I know that it's a dagger.

[image: Picture of different daggers]
I personally use the third style like I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Never thought I'd give handwriting advice here, but I suppose this *does* fall under notation. I agree, the dagger can look like a plus sign. My rendition adds a guard to the dagger's pommel. Additional advantage: it's a single stroke.

[image: Adagger]

Comment: This might end up looking like raising to the $p$-th power for the careless.

Comment: @J.M.: It also looks a bit like a $\varphi$...

Comment: @J.M. Hah, yeah. I swear it's not a p! Nor a $\rho$! Ah, well, it's discernable within the stylesheet of my handwriting. Maybe it can aid another's.

Comment: (P.S. "phi" $\varphi$ and "rho" $\rho$ are different letters. ;))

Comment: @J.M. I posted prior to seeing Will's response. I wouldn't be caught dead writing a $\phi$ that sloppily.

Comment: I personally like to include a [pommel](http://i.imgur.com/Wd7biZS.png)

Comment: I've lost marks trying to draw it this way before.